# Any other way to increase the customer logged in time in Magento-1.9 without increasing server session time session.gc_maxlifetime?

Tags: magento-1.9, security

Any other way to increase the customer logged in time without increasing server session time?

If we give a value as 78,00,000 seconds (3 months) for session.gc_maxlifetime in the php.ini file, then Magento 1.9 logged in customers will be active for three months? Note: Already increased "set Cookie Lifetime" in System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management

Is that safe to set the session.gc_maxlifetime variable in the php.ini file as 3 months?

Answer (score 1):

**First Way:**

```
System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Web -> Session Cookie Management 
Cookie Lifetime 7800000
Cookie Path /
Cookie Domain www.mysite.com
Use HTTP Only No
Cookie Restriction Mode No
```

**Another Way:**

```
FTP Server Root Directory
php.ini file changed to "session.cache_expire = 7800000"
```

**One More Way with Code**

> Path: app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
{

     $adminSessionLifetime = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig(’admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime’); 
       if ($adminSessionLifetime > 7800000) 
       { 
          Mage::getSingleton(’core/cookie’)->setLifetime($adminSessionLifetime); 
       }
}
```